# SEVERE: null com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'Admin' in 'where clause'

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I still could not find out why my SQL statements cannot run on my JAVA program, but they run on the Workbench!

I am trying to make an interface where users can register or login. 
To Register, I have this error:

> SEVERE: null
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'Admin' in 'field list'

I have a username "Admin" on the database that I can see on workbench

Also If I click on the button Clear, and type OK it does not give the error of registering and I can see the table of data I have, because it skips the part of trying to register the code since the strings are empty and runs the else block;

(Code on MyUserApp Class)

```
private void RegisterButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    String username, password, address, dob;
    try {
        // TODO Register very important too!
        username = newUsernameField.getText();
        password = passwordField2.getText();
        address = addressField.getText();
        dob = dateofbField.getText();
if( username == null || password == null || username.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty() || password.length() < 6 ) 
            jLabel6.setText("The information you typed in is not valid. ");
        else{
                this.app.registerUser(app, username, password, dob, address);

                }
        String u = this.app.showDB(app);
        showTableDB.setText(u);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(UserAppUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

(Code on the UI Class)

```
public void registerUser(MyUserApp app, String username, String pw, String dob, String address) throws SQLException{

    String sb = "INSERT INTO javabase.user (iduser, username, password, date_of_birth, address)\n VALUES (" + app.incID()+", "+username+", "+pw+", "+dob+", "+address +");";
    PreparedStatement statement = app.getCon().prepareStatement(sb);
    statement.execute();
}
```

This happens when i try to login
https://prnt.sc/gajpns

And this happens when I try to register:
https://prnt.sc/gak3uh

The code that makes users login is basically this:

```
this.app.login(this.app, username, pw);
```

on the UI class, that calls this one:

```
 public void login(MyUserApp app, String user, String pw) throws SQLException{

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM javabase.user WHERE username = "+ user +" and password = "+pw+";";
    PreparedStatement statement = app.getCon().prepareStatement(sql);
    statement.execute();
}
```

Comment: Learn to use query parameters.  Don't munge query strings.  When you do, you are likely to get hard-to-debug problems, like this one.

Comment: What do you mean? The concatenation of the string with + ?

Comment: I did stringbuilder before and it did not work, and then I came back to doing the whole string to see what was the error because when i put the command on the workbench, it works... but here it does not... dunno why, Thanks in advance

Comment: Check my answer now please, and tell me if it is good and protected from sQL injections, thanks! @GordonLinoff

Comment: When saving a password verifier just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt`, `passlib.hash` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: @zaph oh, here... Thank you, I'll do that for sure , I need to save that comment! You are brilliant! I saw about the brute force thing, but since this was not for a real app and to test, i just encrypted the password, but no you are right and I will improve it yes!

Comment: @zaph sorry for posting so many comments, just a confirmation regarding now the sqli , using parameters is enough right? Because it won't allow user to input " passworddds' OR 1=1. "  for instance, right? The parameter will only allow the string and treat it like a string input for that parameter, right? Or how does it work?

Comment: [NIST](https://www.nist.gov) recommends not changing passwords the user submits **except** removing invisible characters such as the space character is acceptable and generally good to remove since they can't be seen they can be troublesome. So create a function to remove space characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enclose the string literals, such as the user's name or password, by single or double quotes in mysql. If you do not, then mysql parses them as column names.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM javabase.user WHERE username = '"+ user +"' and password = '"+pw+"';";
```

You have to edit all other statements in line with the solution I provided above.

However, pls consider Gordon's advice and use parameters and not string concatenation.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I was using string builder, yeah, but I went back to the old + concatenation because I didnt know what else to do, and then I keep trying different things to isolate the issue...  I tought about the '' quotes but forgot how could i ever do that XD so silly Thank you so much! I knew the problem should be on the sql statement :)

Answer (score -2):

I used SQL Parameters

```
public boolean registerUser(MyUserApp app, String username, String pw, String dob, String address) throws SQLException{

    String sb = "INSERT INTO user (iduser, username, password, date_of_birth, address)\n VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
    PreparedStatement statement = app.getCon().prepareStatement(sb);
    statement.setInt(1, app.incID());
    statement.setString(2, username);
    statement.setString(3, cryptWithMD5(pw));
    statement.setString(4,dob);
    statement.setString(5,address);

    boolean status = statement.execute();
    return status;

     }
```

Comment: When saving a password verifier just using a hash function such as MD5 is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security.

Comment: @zaph regarding the sql injection, is that sufficient? And the password , what should I do, use a different hashing?  My worry is that it must fit on the database and its varchar25 , please help

Comment: @zaph do you mean do verify the input given by the user, if it has a capital letter, or is at least 6 lenght? Even registering i do the 6 lenght test, can you give me some tips of what you mean? :)

Comment: Handling passwords correctly has two aspects: Easy implementation for the developer or security for the user. IMO the morally correct choice is the user's security. 1. It is your choice: user security or varchar25. 2. MD5 provides insufficient security, for Java probably the best choice is PNKFD2 as recommended by NIST. 3. WRT sql injection: [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: @zaph PBKDF2 , you mean :)  I saw your comments, thanks! On it

Comment: @zaph just changed to "long String" something like that, it was quite simple... and used PBKDF2  , so all I have to do now is THANK YOU A LOT for all your advises because they are GREAT! Enjoy your day :) Thank you! :)